# Get Number of A's in Result Table - MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, count

This is the case. In my school all classes prepare excel sheet for each class with marks for each subject in term end test. There are 17 classes. I combine them in to access table. Then again export all data in to excel. make csv file . And import to Mysql Database using phpmyadmin. now I have result table as follow.

```
| ID    | Name      | Religion  | Sinhala   | science   | english   | maths     | History   | Categery 1    | Categery 2    | Categery 3    | Total     | Average   | Rank  |       |
|----   |-------    |---------- |---------  |---------  |---------  |-------    |---------  |------------   |------------   |------------   |-------    |---------  |------ |---    |
| 1     | manoj     | 45        | 65        | 78        | 98        | 67        | 67        | 63            | 76            | 64            | 654       | 62        | 12    |       |
```

Sectional Head Need to get number of students who got >75 for all Subject.

And Number of Student Who got >75 for 8 subject out of 9.

I need to retrieve number of A s, B s (marks >=75) from this table.

Ex.  Student names and Number of A s

Total Number of A for all 9 subject   -   45

Total Number of A for all 8 subject (any 8 subject )   -   45

Total Number of A for all 7 subject (any 7 subject )   -   45

I Tried following SQL Statement

```
SELECT COUNT(SELECT COUNT() 
             FROM result 
             WHERE religion >=75 
               AND Math >=75) 
FROM result
```

I read about same scenario in stack overflow.

[Access 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258716/access-2010-find-students-with-select-grades)

this one get some point. but I cant solve it for my scenario.

Comment: Please clean up your formatting.  This question is illegible.

Comment: now is it ok? @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: It's still missing the query that you wrote to attempt to do this. It's also missing an explanation as to which part of that query is not functioning correctly.

Comment: Hi @ManojMadushantha I've modified your question to include code-block formatting. Hope it helps!

Comment: @hd  Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY studentName` and `SUM(grade = 'A') AS numberOfAs`.

[Quick answer bc question is quickly formatted]

Comment: I edit the question. so you get narrow idea. there is no grade column. I have to get it by >=75,   >=65

Comment: Then adapt what's in the `SUM`: `SUM(religion >= 75 AND math >= 75)` or whatever conditions that makes a "grade A"

Comment: Finally Solve it!  I change Data schema as Student, Subject and result. Then do Following query

Comment: [code]ELECT s.Name, s.Class, resul.Number_of_A FROM (SELECT s.STUID, COUNT(*) AS Number_of_A FROM student s JOIN results r ON s.STUID=r.STUID JOIN subject su ON su.SUBID=r.SUBID WHERE r.Mark>=75 GROUP BY s.STUID LIMIT 0,700) AS resul join student s ON resul.STUID=s.STUID WHERE resul.Number_of_A=6[/code]